# Can I use a PDF boarding pass for Ryanair?

Tags: tickets, check-in, ryanair

My agent sent me a PDF via email. Can I use it at the airport? Or do I have to use the RyanAir app? Or do I have to print a boarding pass?

Comment: the PDF in your email is probably not a boarding pass, but an e-ticket or a receipt. Does it say BOARDING PASS on it?

Comment: What does your booking say about check-in? You don’t get a boarding pass unless you’ve checked in, and agents don’t normally check-in on behalf of a passenger. Have you looked at https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/check-in/important-check-in-information?

Comment: What's in the PDF?

Answer (score 6):

Ryanair are often strict about enforcing arbitrary rules. The only kind of boarding pass which can be used on your phone for boarding a Ryanair flight is accessed using the Ryanair app. Using a PDF of the boarding pass may result in you being required to pay a [£/€20 printing fee](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/check-in/boarding-cards). Ryanair make a big proportion of their profit from levying fines like this so it is likely you will be charged.

Either print out your PDF boarding pass before arriving at the airport, or use the app to access a mobile boarding pass. Note that only EU/EEA/Swiss/UK citizens can use mobile boarding passes if the flight is not entirely domestic or within the Schengen area. All other nationalities must print their boarding pass and get it stamped at the Ryanair customer service or check in desk before security.

Answer (score 1):

If the PDF is a boarding pass, it won’t be accepted:

> Hi Simon, we don't accept PDF boarding pass, you will need to print it out.

([Ryanair Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/ryanair/status/507144011770241024?lang=en))

You have a few options:

- Print your boarding pass at home or at the airport (for a fee depending by country)
- Use the boarding passes on your phone (either in the app, Wallet for iPhone or Google Pay for Android)